# How to use the ListView_GetBkImage macro in C#

Tags: c#, .net, pinvoke

How can I use the ListView_GetBkImage macro:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb761246(v=VS.85).aspx

... from a C#/WinForms application?  I think this macro just wraps the `SendMessage` method, but I'm not sure.  I couldn't find any C#-based samples on this.

Basically I'm trying to get a LVBKIMAGE ( http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb774742(v=VS.85).aspx ) structure that references the Desktop's background bitmap.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot. A macro is processed at compile time by the C/C++ compiler, but you want to access the binary library. You will just have to find the macro in the source, see what it does and do the same in your C# code. It shouldn't be anything too complex. Download the Platform SDK if you don't already have it and look in the .h file mentioned in the documentation.

**Edit:** OK, so the macro is defined as:

```
#define ListView_GetBkImage(hwnd, plvbki) \
    (BOOL)SNDMSG((hwnd), LVM_GETBKIMAGE, 0, (LPARAM)(plvbki))
```

`SNDMSG` is simply defined as `SendMessage`. LVM_GETBKIMAGE is an integer - it's 0x1045 for the ASCII version and 0x108B for the Unicode version. (You probably want the Unicode version if you're unsure.) So the entire thing resolves to:

```
(BOOL)SendMessage(hwnd, 0x108B, 0, plvbki)
```

There should be easy enough to map to C#. Look in System.Windows.Forms using Reflector to see how Microsoft have imported the SendMessage function. It will be marked internal, so you cannot call it, but you can copy it. `plvbki` is a pointer to a  struct - you'll need to create a C# equivalent of `LVBKIMAGE`. Actually, MS have probably done that for you too, so look around for that.

Comment: It's too complex for someone without a C/C++ background, unfortunately. As far as I could deduce from what I looked at, it's ultimately some way of calling `SendMessage` with some flags and pointers and somehow coming back with a filled-out structure.

Comment: OK, I've looked into it and updated the post. See how you go with that.